# Redirect a .jpg using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I needed to redirect "example.com/image/img.jpg" to "example.com/view/img.jpg"

Therefore I've used

```
RewriteRule (^|.*?/)image/(.*)$ /$1view/$2 [R=302,L,NC]
```

But, still if I try to visit "example.com/image/img.jpg" it won't redirect. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to add `RewriteEngine On` in your `.htaccess` before the RewriteRule, it could help

Comment: I already have `RewriteEngine On` at the beginning of my `.htaccess`. Do I have to add it twice? I mean before the `RewriteRule` also?

Comment: Once is enough. I tested the rule on my webserver and it works. Is the `.htaccess` file processed by the web server? Check the AllowOverride directive in server config, or make a syntax error in .htaccess and see if it results in error 500.

Comment: I made a syntax error in `.htaccess` & whole website went error 500. Except "example.com/image/img.jpg". It displayed the img.jpg. Seems that the `.htaccess` file won't process there. :(

Comment: is there another `.htaccess` in the `image/` directory? If so, add the rule inside that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I needed to redirect "example.com/image/img.jpg" to "example.com/view/img.jpg"

Apparently the above examples are not accurate as your rule shows directories `image` and `view` can be at any level in the corresponding URL directory structures.

If that's the case, you may try this in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)?image/([^.]+)\.jpg [NC]
RewriteRule .*             /%1view/%2.jpg        [R,L,NC]
```

In case `image` and `view` directories are indeed at the first level as described in the examples, replace the last 2 lines with this one:

```
RewriteRule ^image/(.*)   /view/$1 [R,L,NC]
```

Replace [R,L,NC] with [R=301,L,NC] for permanent redirection or with [L,NC] for internal mapping.